# How to display content of an svn repository?

Tags: svn, download, svn-checkout

I check out (down load) subdirectories from our svn repository in the following way: `svn co file:///home/svnrepository/aaa/bbb/ccc` and it works.

The problem is that I am doing it "blindly" because, at the moment, I do not know how can I see the content of the svn repository. If I use `cd` with auto-complete (pressing tabs) I get `cd file:///home/svnrepository/` (so, it looks like my operating system sees that this directory exists). However, when I execute the last `cd` I get: `Directory is not found`.

If I have `cd file:///home/svnrepository/` in the command line and press tabs I get the following output:

```
conf/       db/         format      hooks/      locks/      README.txt
```

It is strange, that in this way I do not get `aaa` subdirectory that I way able check out.

`ls file:///home/svnrepository/` also does not work (directory is not found).

So, now my problem is that I need to down load `tools` subdirectory from the repository but I do not know where it is (in what directory) and I also do not know how to find out where it is. For example I do not know if I should type `svn co file:///home/svnrepository/tools` or `svn co file:///home/svnrepository/aaa/tools` or `svn co file:///home/svnrepository/aaa/bbb/tools`.

Does any body know how can I browse the file structure of an svn server?

**EDIT**

I was able to execute `cd /home/svnrepository/` (so, I needed to remove `file://`). But in this directory I do not see `aaa` subdirectory which I was able to check out with `svn co file:///home/svnrepository/aaa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For listing directory from SVN you can use

```
svn ls file:///home/svnrepository/
```

keep going further with each svn ls command and reach the file you need.

Note-
In your case, the repository looks to be local and thus you can actually do ls directly without using "file":

```
ls /home/svnrepository/
```